# Android Canvas background transparent

Tags: android, bitmap, icons, maps, android-canvas

I draw on a `bitmap` an icon with a stroke color. That origin `bitmap` has a white background. On that with `canvas` I draw a second `bitmap` with a stroke (circle).

What happens is, that the resulting bitmap has on Nexus 7 or Galaxy S2 (both hdpi) a transparent backround. On other devices is all fine (its still white).

That bitmap is used as a marker for gmaps.

```
public Bitmap getMarkerBitmap(){
    Bitmap clusterBackground = backgroundImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(clusterBackground);
    int xAnchor = (clusterBackground.getWidth() / 2)-(newIcon.getWidth() / 2);
    int yAnchor = (clusterBackground.getHeight()/2)-(newIcon.getHeight() / 2);
    final Point center = new Point(xAnchor,yAnchor);
    canvas.drawBitmap(newIcon, center.x, center.y,paint);
    return drawCircle(canvas,clusterBackground);
}

private Bitmap drawCircle(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap){
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidthInPx);
    int centerX = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX,centerY,centerY-strokeWidthInPx/2,paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

When I set the background to white per `Paint` object, then it works, but then the whole `Rect` is white, my icon is rounded !

Comment: Are you sure that your `backgroundImage` is not transparent from beginning ?

Comment: Damn ur right, wrong icon in assets with the same name!

Comment: That happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: Can u write an answer so I can accept it, which can happen to anybody :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks correct, make sure your `backgroundImage` is not transparent from the beginning.
As you outlined, there are different resource folders for different screen resolutions, so different files can lead to different results on different devices.